# creating multiple password in PHP without db

Tags: javascript, php, html

Am new web development, I'm curious to know on how to create a multiple password in php without db that will redirect my clients to a different pages

```
$error = "";
$success = "";

if(isset($_POST['Tracking1$btnTrack'])){
    $uname = $_POST['uname'];
    if($uname == "AAA13"){
        $error = "";
        $success = "Welcome ".$uname." !!!";
        //redirect to another page on successful login
        header("Location: fetching13");
    } else {
        $error = "tracking code not found !!!";
        header("refresh:2;url=Tracking");//
        $success = "";
    }
}

$error = "";
$success = "";

if(isset($_POST['Tracking1$btnTrack'])){
    $uname = $_POST['uname'];
    if($uname == "AAA14"){

        $error = "";
        $success = "Welcome ".$uname." !!!";
        //redirect to another page on successful login
        header("Location: fetching14");
    } else {
        $error = "tracking code not found !!!";
        header("refresh:2;url=Tracking");//
        $success = "";
    }
}

$error = "";
$success = "";

if(isset($_POST['Tracking1$btnTrack'])){
    $uname = $_POST['uname'];
    if($uname == "AAA15"){
        $error = "";
        $success = "Welcome ".$uname." !!!";
        //redirect to another page on successful login
        header("Location: fetching15");
    } else {
        $error = "tracking code not found !!!";
        header("refresh:2;url=Tracking");//
        $success = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome jennifer!  It would be helpful to know what you are using the authentication for, there is probably an answer here on SO for most use cases, and if you could explain your use case with a little more detail, I would be happy to help look for one, or someone could write up a new answer for your specific use case. Some helpful clarifications: What is the use case? More specifically, what is the authentication being used for? How many identities are required? Just a few, or will users be able to create new ones?

Comment: @Raleigh I'm new here and am also new in web development, i dont know much about PHP, i was trying to use php code that will create multiple password without DB to redirect my clients to different page, i sucessfully created the codes but so said that only one of the password is working and the rest keep saying invalid

Answer (score 0):

Use **OR operator** (||) in if condition, where you check the password.

```
if($uname == "AAA13" || $uname == "BBB13")
```

But keep in mind, that this is not the best way to create a login system.

I assume you're doing this just to learn.

In addition, remember that anyone can access your *fetching13.php*, if you don't check if the user is logged in or not.

**EDIT:** It seems you're quite new to programming. I would recommend to check [PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/index.php), before creating another thread here.

Comment: Yes you're right . i'm doing it just to learn pls can u help me out, should i send u all the codes i created so u can help me in rectifying it?